# How I can internationalize variables within the function _e () __ (), etc?

Tags: plugins, php, localization

I have intro function variables and i wish internationalize dynamic.

I have the follow code:

```
_e($widget['description'], MyStaticClass::$i18n_prefix);
```

When I run the poedit this internationalization (`$widget['description']`) is not done.

How I can it dynamic?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use `"$widget['description']"` in the translation file or are you using the _content_ of `$widget['description']`? Please post [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Comment: @s_ha_dum: I'm trying to use the content of $widget['description']. This does not give me any error, I just want to come out later translated content so far manually. Thanks

Comment: Ok, that is good. Now for the debugging information...

Comment: I doubt it will help but you could force that value to a string by putting the variable inside double quotes. It is worth the time it would take to test it.